# Word for strength of will

Tags: single-word-requests

As the title shows, can anyone tell me what is the word for *strength of will*?

For example,

> Her *strength of will* was extraordinary.

Comment: I think this is Not Constructive. There are any number of terms available, and even with a lot more context, I doubt it would ever be possible to identify a single "correct" answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some other options:

Her ***resolve*** was extraordinary.

Her ***iron will*** was extraordinary.

Answer (score 3):

*[Willpower](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/willpower#Noun)* (“The unwavering strength of will to carry out one’s wishes”) is suitable.  Also consider  *[fortitude](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fortitude#Noun)* (“Mental or emotional strength that enables courage in the face of adversity”).

Terms with slightly-less-positive slants include  *[bloody-mindedness](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bloody-minded)* ([obstinacy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obstinacy#Noun) or *[stubbornness](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stubbornness#Noun)* or *[doggedness](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doggedness#Noun)*).  The latter has synonyms that include  persistence; perseverance; tenacity; stubbornness.

Answer (score 1):

Synonyms for [*Strength of will*](http://dictionary.sensagent.com/strength+of+will/en-en/):

*aplomb, composure, force of will, mind, poise, possession, self-command, self-control, self-possession, self-will, will, willpower, will power*

[Also](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/willpower) (*will power*):
*perseverance, self-command, self-possession, firmness of purpose, resoluteness, resolve, firmness, resolution, nerves, drive, determination, grit, self-discipline, single-mindedness, fixity of purpose*.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps [Stoicism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stoicism) (A real or pretended indifference to pleasure or pain; insensibility; impassiveness)? Perhaps too negative though?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoicism#Modern_usage) says that in modern usage, “The word "stoic" commonly refers to someone indifferent to pain, pleasure, grief, or joy. The modern usage [is] "person who represses feelings or endures patiently"...”  In short, it doesn't denote (and often doesn't connote) strength of will.  Novels and movies are full of stoic villains who ultimately are craven.

Comment: I agree, but without further context regarding the intended connotation, I think 'stoicism' is still a valid suggestion.